# Hello..i have a table with family_id and city .I need one city for each family id where majority of the people live in

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBmpH.jpg)

```
SELECT
  family_id,
  MIN((city)) keep (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY COUNT (city) DESC)
FROM FAMILY_MEMBERS
GROUP BY family_id;
```

> error:ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
>   00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>   Error at Line: 116 Column: 24

[Family_members](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBmpH.jpg)

Comment: Provide more details about the table to get a concrete answer please. :)

Comment: I have a table as in I attached. From table lets take family id-5. Majority of people of family id-5 live in Jefferson city. Similarly majority of people of family id-3 live in Hermitage. So in Output I need to **familyid*   *City***** --- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 5  Jefferson city  --------------------------------------------------------------------------3    Hermitage .... This way I need Family_id and the city in which majority people that  particular family_id live.                                ______THanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can not use a window-function (dense_rank()) together with GROUP BY. If you need to do both, you'll have to make a sub-select.

EDIT:
Here's my suggestion:

```
SELECT y.family_id, y.City
FROM 
(SELECT x.family_id, x.City, x.Member_count,
row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY x.family_id ORDER BY x.Member_count DESC) rn
FROM
(SELECT family_id, City, COUNT(*) Member_count
FROM FAMILY_MEMBERS
GROUP BY family_id, City) x) y
WHERE y.rn = 1;
```

Comment: thanks.But this gives more than one city for each family_id.I need only the people's residing city from each family_id. That means only one city as result for each family_id

Comment: Fixed it - try again. :)

Comment: Thanks so much>>helped me alot

Comment: I recently joined into this and I shud get minimum points reputation to do so.